# Своё расширение для CubeMX

Tags: stm32, embedded, кодогенераторы

Разрабатываю ПО для STM32. Есть библиотека, которая используется практически во всех проектах. В проектах использую CubeMX, код инициализации библиотеки зависит от настроек CubeMX. Задача состоит в том, чтобы CubeMX генерировал код инициализации этой библиотеки. Знаю, что в CubeMX можно установить дополнительные расширения, полагаю задача сводится к написанию своего расширения для CubeMX.
Хочу получить ответы на вопросы:

1. Возможно ли сделать своё, пользовательское расширение для CubeMX?
2. Если да, то где взять информацию о написании таковых, желательно с примером?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Да, можно.
2. Подробное описание процесса на сайте ST в документе под кодовым названием UM2739.